# Calculating elevation at point on line using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, elevation

I have two line layers showing stormwater and sanitary sewer pipes.  The attribute tables for both layers show elevations for the upstream and downstream ends of each pipe.  I have a point layer showing where they cross in planimetric view.  Many of the pipes have more than one crossing point.  The attribute table for the crossing points includes IDs for both pipes.

I need to find out which pipe is higher at the crossing points.  I'm using ArcGIS Pro with a Basic license and unfortunately I have minimal coding skills.

Can anyone suggest an approach for this?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, linear referencing is what you need. However, you would need to assume a constant slope of the pipes, otherwise you cannot always solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Aha-- linear referencing.  Perhaps the obviousness of the answer is why I didn't get any replies!